# Making 4 columns into 1 column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 3 tables that looks something like this **(but with 40,000+ observations and 40 variables)**

```
   in1  out1       in2  out2         in3 out3
    1    2          2    4             3   5
    1    3          2    5             3   6
    1    3          2    6             3   7
```

I want to take columns out1, out2, and out3 and make them one column, then create a new table that looks like this:

```
in out
1  2
1  3
1  3
2  4 
2  5
2  6
3  5 
3  6
3  7
```

So basically I want to take 3 huge tables I have, combine them into 1 table and then merge (stack? I don't know the correct wording) 3 specific columns together into 1 column with a new name.

I've tried a few methods such as:

```
table$out <- cbind(table1$out1, table2$out2, table3$out3)
```

but I get errors like this:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, out, value = c(0.98, 0.59, 0.69,  : 
>         replacement has 31467 rows, data has 42141
>       number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)

I'm sorry if this is a very simple question.. I might just be overthinking it

Comment: I think you mean `rbind`. Think of them as `r`ow`bind` and `c`olumn`bind`.

Comment: `data.frame(In = unlist(df[,c(1,3,5)]), Out = unlist(df[,c(2,4,6)]))`